# Playground execution failed: <EXPR>:15:33: error: type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'

Tags: ios, if-statement, for-loop, swift, logical-operators

I am creating a simple [Fizz Buzz Generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz) with Swift.

I receive the following error:

```
Playground execution failed: <EXPR>:15:33: error: type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'
    } else if (number % 3 == 0) && (number % 5) {
```

Here is what I have:

```
for number in 1...100 {
    if (number % 3 == 0) {
        println("Fizz")
    } else if (number % 5 == 0) {
        println("Buzz")
    } else if (number % 3 == 0) && (number % 5) {
        println("Fizz Buzz")
    } else {
        println(number)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing some of your logic. Change

```
else if (number % 3 == 0) && (number % 5)
```

to

```
else if (number % 3 == 0) && (number % 5 == 0)
```